# Ruby is_a? problems

Tags: ruby

I have a constructor for an object Program that validates an argument to make sure it is an integer:

```
def initialize(programid,*other_args)
  unless programid.is_a?(Integer) then
    raise TypeError
  end
  @programid = programid
  @name = other_args['name']
end
```

and when I create a new instance

```
my_prog = Program::new(13453)
```

It gives me this error:

```
can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Which should not be happening because I'm not trying to do a conversion. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me. Is there something else going on that is called when you call Program:new? What happens if you have puts programid.class before your unless?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Can you post a complete program which demonstrates the error?

Comment: Turns out it is related to how I am using *other_args.  I thought I could use it as an hash but it seems I cannot

    @name = other_args['name']

Comment: If you would like named, optional arguments the common ruby idiom is to define the method with a single, optional argument that defaults to empty Hash e.g. def initialize(programid, options = {}) and then it can be called with something like Program.new(13453, :name => "foo) and you can access options[:name] in the method body

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't caused by is_a?

"can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)" is caused by this line:

```
@name = other_args['name']
```

other_args is an array in your sample code not a hash - that's why ruby is trying to convert "name" into an Integer (and failing)

If you call a method with the keyword argument syntax, it works as though all the keyword args are bundled into a hash which is supplied as the last argument to the method call.

Notice the difference in method declarations:

Yours:

```
def initialize(programid,*other_args)
```

Subba Rao's

```
def initialize(*other_args)
```

That's a neat simplification - turn all the arguments into a single hash, shift out the first arg (which the code assumes you have). Then provide a default empty hash as an alternative if you didn't supply any other args:

```
other_args.first || {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
  def initialize(*other_args)
    programid   = other_args.shift
    other_args   = other_args.first || {}
    unless programid.is_a?(Integer) then
      raise TypeError
    end
    @programid = programid
    @name = other_args['name']
    puts @name
    puts @programid
  end
end
Program::new(13453)
Program::new(13453,'name'=>"North Wolf")
```